# How Are These Diagrams Made?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate

I'm working on a my first paper right now which has quite a few diagrams. So far I've been able to get by using tikz, but my last two digrams are quite a bit more complicated than the first two and I'm afraid I wont be able to get the look I want from tikz. I came across this blog post where they were able to achieve the look I want, but I cannot find any references to how they made their diagrams. Could anyone point me in the right direction? It seems to be less about machine learning and more about academia so I figured here is the best place to ask.

Here is the blog post: http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/

Comment: Have you considered asking the author(s) of this blog post?

Comment: Some of them may use tikz. You could use tikz at least for the nice borders and creating the boxes, some people even would create the whole graphic with tikz or similar. Personally I would recommend inkscape for creating nice looking vector graphics. The best way to include them is then to export as pdf and use includegraphics when using pdflatex. This is not a full answer, as your question is rather off-topic here. At tex.stackexchange.com People will probably provide the full code to create such a bert graphic ;-).

Comment: Inkscape as suggested by allo is nice, but can be a bit tricky to work with. For simple diagrams, something like MS Powerpoint can produce surprisingly good results.

Comment: Built many diagrams using the shapes etc in Excel... quite handy having diagrams labels and numbers linked to calculated cells, you can produce different versions quite easily...

Comment: Echoing what @astronat says, PowerPoint has become much better recently. I never thought I would say that...

Comment: @allo "People will probably provide the full code to create such a bert graphic" I would  not recommend doing that, as "[do-it-for-me questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/what-is-a-do-it-for-me-question?noredirect=1&lq=1)" are not exactly welcome there…

Comment: @Clément that's an important caveat. However, the folks over at tex.se are *incredibly* helpful.

Comment: I think this is a better fit for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ than here, but I agree that better still would be to contact the authors and ask.

Comment: @Clément You should not ask "Do this for me", but in my experience you probably *will* get answers on tex.se how to fully reproduce the graphics even when you only ask for a hint. The people over there are extremely competent and helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi thanks for all the comments!

I asked the author on Twitter and it turns out the he uses Keynote to make those diagrams, and not some obscure library written in python or TeX.

Comment: "obscure", Tikz? You're going to make enemies :-) Glad you found your answer.